# Trac permission denied for SVN repo

Tags: permissions, svn, trac

I'm running Apache2,SVN & Trac on OpenSUSE. SVN works like a charm. I've initialized trac environment for one of my SVN repositories for trac to show source code in it's repo browser and I set the repository up in the Trac web admin. I also ran the trac-admin resync for that repo without problems.

Trouble is when I open the Trac repo browser I get:

```
"can't open file: /srv/svn/repos/myrepo/format, access denied)"
```

error. I checked the permissions and:

- apache runs as **wwwrun**
- tracd runs as **wwwrun**
- the whole subtree /srv/svn/... belongs to **svn** group and the group has **rw** perms all the way down to the "format" file
- **wwwrun** is in the **svn** group

I also did the perms check:

```
$ sudo -u wwwrun cat /srv/svn/repos/myrepo/format
```

and got it printed out without trouble.

So in my opinion there shoud not be any permission conflict. Any idea what else to check?

Thanks in advance!

---

**Edit**: it works if I chown the whole svn dir with the apache user running trac (in my case wwwrun). But I don't think this should be done this way (groups are ment for this, right?).

---

Trac 0.12.2, svnserve version 1.6.17 (r1128011)

Comment: Sorry, I can't comment, this is not really an answer, but what is the output of ls -l /srv/svn/repos/myrepo/format ?

Comment: Cheers, sure it is: -rwxrwx--- 1 honza svn 2 Mar  3 15:01 /srv/svn/repos/myrepo/format